# Remove port number from URL in parallelClient Java

Tags: java, maven, parallel-processing

I have used "prepareHttpPost" method to POST the data to set of URLs using parallelClient in JAVA. By default it appends the port number :80 at the end of my each URLs.So, i am getting 404 page not found from each URLs. I need to remove the port number at the end of URLs.

Below is my code to verify.

```
private List<String> postHostsList = Arrays.asList("HOST1/test.php",
        "HOST2/testing.php");
parallelClient = new ParallelClient();
    String requestBody = "<JSON DATA>";
    parallelClient.prepareHttpPost("").setConcurrency(20).setTargetHostsFromList(postHostsList)
            .setHttpHeaders(new ParallecHeader().addPair("Content-Type", "application/json"))
            .setHttpEntityBody(requestBody).execute(new ParallecResponseHandler() {

                public void onCompleted(ResponseOnSingleTask responseOnSingleTask, Map<String, Object> map) {
                    responseOnSingleTask.getStatusCode().replaceAll("", "_");
                    System.out.println("Status Code =>" + responseOnSingleTask.getStatusCode());
                    System.out.println("Response  =>" + responseOnSingleTask.getResponseContent());
                }
            });
    parallelClient.releaseExternalResources();
```

Comment: You should put the `/test.php` as  `prepareHttpPost` param, instead of using it in the host.

Comment: But the hostname and postfix URLs are different to each other. so how can i put /test.php as prepareHttpPost for all http connections?

Comment: Then read the docs here: http://www.parallec.io/docs/submit-task/#apis-on-variable-replacement-for-heterogeneous-requests